# Running Arquillian tests with Maven dependencies in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, maven, junit, intellij-idea, jboss-arquillian

When deploying an Arquillian test with Intellij using pom dependencies like:

```
    File[] libs = Maven.resolver().offline()
                                  .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                                  .importRuntimeDependencies()
                                  .resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();
```

The test run just fine in other IDEs, but with IntelliJ, there is an error that does not let execute the test properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go to Edit Configurations (under Run menu), select Defaults branch and
>   then JUnit. You can see that Working directory is set to project’s
>   directory. That’s why pom.xml could not be found in this location.
>   Fortunately it can be changed either to MAVEN_REPOSITORY or to
>   MODULE_DIR and the latter is exactly what you want. Changing that and
>   saving it in defaults makes the issue above disappear.
>
> Now you can run your tests from IntelliJ even if you have maven
>   dependencies to be included in your @Deployment archive.

As seen here: http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2012/10/24/arquillian-tests-with-maven-deps-intellij/